# Remap keyboard like remote controller PGUP/PGDN keys to Next/Prev media keys

Tags: linux, keyboard, remote, remapping

I bought the media remote controller for PC to use on my Linux machine. The controller acts like a keyboard for some of the keys, but lacks Next/Prev media buttons functionality.

So I wanted to remap PageUp/PageDown on that remote controller to Next/Prev.
I managed to remap Prior to XF86AudioPrev and Next to XF86AudioPrev. However this does not work as the media keys generate a different events.

[Here is what the media key generates (captured by `xev`)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxXHX.png)

[Here is what the remote mapping does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu4qu.png)

How can I map the keys on remote so they would act as media keys?

Kind regards,

Piotr

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.